# iOS crash: respondsToSelector: message sent to deallocated instance

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios7, crash, crash-reports

I am using a `UINavigationController` as `rootviewController` and storyboard segue for `pushingViewController`. I have many viewcontrollers in my app. I pass them using push view controller only.

**Crash scenario: (can reproduce)**

1. I have a Products list viewController and I will navigate to products detail viewController when I tap on product in the list using tap Gesture recognizer.
2. From the detail view controller, I will be pushed to cart item viewController which displays all selected products when I tap a button named 'Addd to cart'.
3. If I try to pay for all the products I want to choose a contact from the people picker, when I press pay button, it will present peopelpickerController as `modalViewController` and when I choose a contact it gets crashed.
4. Crash occurs only when move to and fro from products list view controlelr to peoplepicker contoller. When I debugged using instrument I got crash saying deallocated instance receiving message. 
   I have included the method where I am getting crash. But i never tried to call the method from any controller.

**Code...**

```
//choosing contact and people picker delegate
- (IBAction) chooseContacts: (id) sender {
    picker = [
        [ABPeoplePickerNavigationController alloc] init];
    picker.peoplePickerDelegate = self;
    [self presentViewController: picker animated: YES completion: nil];
}

#pragma mark - Addressbook delegate methods

- (void) peoplePickerNavigationControllerDidCancel: (ABPeoplePickerNavigationController * ) peoplePicker {
    [self dismissViewControllerAnimated: YES completion: nil];
}


- (BOOL) peoplePickerNavigationController: (ABPeoplePickerNavigationController * ) peoplePicker
shouldContinueAfterSelectingPerson: (ABRecordRef) person {
    [self dismissViewControllerAnimated: YES completion: ^ {
        [self displayPerson: person];
    }];

    return NO;
}
```

Crash occurs in the below method at the line `performSegueWithIdentifier`,

```
#pragma mark- Tap gesture delegates

-(void)tapGestureFirstImage:(UITapGestureRecognizer *)sender
{
    UIImageView *image = (UIImageView *)sender.view;
    if (image.tag < [_productsArray count]) {
            [MBProgressHUD showHUDAddedTo:self.view animated:YES];
        productDetailDictionary = [_productsArray objectAtIndex:image.tag];
        NSLog(@"%@",productDetailDictionary);
        [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"productDetailSeague" sender:sender];
    }
    NSLog(@"imageView.Tag %ld",(long)image.tag);

}
```

Crash Log:

```
Exception Type:  EXC_CRASH (SIGABRT)
Exception Codes: 0x0000000000000000, 0x0000000000000000
Triggered by Thread:  0

Thread 0 Crashed:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x39cb11fc __pthread_kill + 8
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x39d1aa2e pthread_kill + 54
2   libsystem_c.dylib               0x39c61ff8 abort + 72
3   libc++abi.dylib                 0x38f90cd2 abort_message + 70
4   libc++abi.dylib                 0x38fa96e0 default_terminate_handler() + 248
5   libobjc.A.dylib                 0x396f291e _objc_terminate() + 190
6   libc++abi.dylib                 0x38fa71c4 std::__terminate(void (*)()) + 76
7   libc++abi.dylib                 0x38fa6a18 __cxa_throw + 112
8   libobjc.A.dylib                 0x396f277e objc_exception_throw + 246
9   CoreFoundation                  0x2ef5be88 +[NSException raise:format:] + 100
10  UIKit                           0x317b9590 -[UIViewController _preferredInterfaceOrientationForPresentationInWindow:fromInterfaceOrientation:] + 496
11  UIKit                           0x317b7dce -[UIWindowController transition:fromViewController:toViewController:target:didEndSelector:animation:] + 2054
12  UIKit                           0x317b6e20 -[UIViewController presentViewController:withTransition:completion:] + 4664
13  UIKit                           0x31992cae -[UIViewController presentModalViewController:animated:] + 26
14  DHCC Events                     0x0008f0c0 0x38000 + 356544
15  libdispatch.dylib               0x39bd5d18 _dispatch_call_block_and_release + 8
16  libdispatch.dylib               0x39bdbd16 _dispatch_after_timer_callback$VARIANT$mp + 46
17  libdispatch.dylib               0x39bd5d04 _dispatch_client_callout + 20
18  libdispatch.dylib               0x39bde7fe _dispatch_source_invoke$VARIANT$mp + 258
19  libdispatch.dylib               0x39bdc73a _dispatch_main_queue_callback_4CF$VARIANT$mp + 186
20  CoreFoundation                  0x2ef26814 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_SERVICING_THE_MAIN_DISPATCH_QUEUE__ + 4
21  CoreFoundation                  0x2ef250e8 __CFRunLoopRun + 1296
22  CoreFoundation                  0x2ee8fc22 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 518
23  CoreFoundation                  0x2ee8fa06 CFRunLoopRunInMode + 102
24  GraphicsServices                0x33b8327e GSEventRunModal + 134
25  UIKit                           0x31733044 UIApplicationMain + 1132
26  DHCC Events                     0x00041ad6 0x38000 + 39638
27  libdyld.dylib                   0x39bfaab4 start + 0
```

Appreciate your help.

Comment: Can you show the crash.

Answer (score 0):

On `-(void)tapGestureFirstImage:(UITapGestureRecognizer *)sender`

you perform the segue with

`[self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"productDetailSeague" sender:sender];`

but I think the sender should be `self` and not `sender`..

**UPDATE**

Do you try to perform segue while `picker` is active? In this case `self` may be deallocated, so you can try to perform segue after `picker` is dismissed:

```
[picker dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:^{[self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"productDetailSeague" sender:self];}];
```

Comment: I was thinking possibly the same. Or even `nil`.

Comment: I will try this and let you know.

Comment: @Logunath you really need to put the crash log in your question. Without it we are all just guessing!

Comment: Guys, pushing the controller using storyboard identifier instead of perforseguewithIdentifier and presentModalViewController doesn't create any crashes. presenting the controller only crashes.